# Using Disqus, how can I get a list of recent comments from posts, and have them link back to the original post?

Tags: disqus

I want to display the 10 most recent comments made from all the blog posts that are using Disqus and display them in a sidebar, then be able to click on the comment and be taken to the original post.

An plus would be to be able to leave out our own comments from the list.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here is a script which will do your job

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://funbutlearn.disqus.com/recent_comments_widget.js?num_items=10&hide_avatars=0&avatar_size=40&excerpt_length=200"></script>
```

If you want to embed a combo (all-in-one) plugin then copy following script

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://funbutlearn.disqus.com/combination_widget.js?num_items=10&hide_mods=0&color=grey&default_tab=recent&excerpt_length=70"></script>
```

You can even apply CSS to make these more attractive.

Answer (score 7):

[What about using this](http://yourblog.disqus.com/latest.rss), then Yahoo Pipes for excluding your own comments (i-e. a filter based on the name of the author), and then a RSS parser such as RSSDisplay for displaying the comments on your sidebar?

Comment: yahoo pipes how nostalgic.,

Answer (score 3):

Disqus folks told us we'd need to make a custom script for this, but it turns out that you can find a widget all ready to go under /admin/tools/widgets/ then choose recent comments.

Haven't gotten into modifying it yet, but you can get the most recent comments there. It has a link to the commenter, a link to the original thread and 'time ago'. It's a start.

I also found this link: http://aaronjwhite.org/index.php/component/content/article/5-php/8-creating-a-recent-comments-widget-with-disquss-api-and-php
Creating A Recent Comments Widget With Disqus's API and PHP

Answer (score 3):

You can get them at http://[your_qisqus_shortname].disqus.com/latest.rss :)