# Questions about DISQUS - get comments and comment count

Tags: php, user-interface, disqus

I'm trying to achieve a few things with DISQUS as demonstrated in the picture below (boxed in red) for my [comics website](http://www.hittingtreeswithsticks.com/?action=viewimage&site=comics&id=66)...

- Get comment count of a particular comic
- Get specific comments, like most recent and most popular
- Truncate the comment, but allow the user to click *read more* to either expand it or link them to the actual comic

[image]

**1) Get comment count:**

To get comment count, I've followed [DISQUS' guide](http://htws.disqus.com/admin/universalcode/#comment-count), but it just gives me a link to where the comments are on the comic... and not the total number... They say:

> Append #disqus_thread to the href attribute in your links. This will
>   tell Disqus which links to look up and return the comment count. For
>   example:

```
<a href="http://foo.com/bar.html#disqus_thread">Link</a>.
```

But how would I get that count if my url string was like this:

`<a href=".?action=viewimage&site=comics&id=66">Link</a>`

So my questions are:

- Where would I append `#disqus_thread`?
- How can I get the comments count from that one comic URL and display those total comments on another page?
- Why does it just give me a link to the comments and not the comment number for that associated comic?

---

**2) Get specific comments, like most recent or most popular**

I haven't really found any documentation on this with the exception of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10838100/using-disqus-how-can-i-get-a-list-of-recent-comments-from-posts-and-have-them) where they say I'd probably need to write my own script...

---

**3) Truncate comments**

If #2 is possible at all, then how would I be able to truncate it?

Thanks!

Comment: Is this for a wordpress site?

Comment: @bretterer it's for a custom php site